# Searching keywords in thousands of c and h files

Tags: java, elasticsearch, search, full-text-search, eclipse-cdt

We have around two  thousand .c and .h files. And we have around 1500 macros to be searched in these .c and .h files.

We have to do the search through our java programming.

Is there any  built in exe's or API's that are fast enough to do this kind of operation?

We would like to get the information which file, and line no's where the macro is being used.

Does CDT gives this information?

Comment: Look into ctags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CDT can give you this information. To use it programmatically, you would need to do something like write a CDT plugin, create an Eclipse project containing your source files, index the project, and run your plugin on it.

Your plugin could use APIs like `IIndex.findMacros()` to find macro bindings matching a given name (a **binding** is CDT's representation of a semantic entity like a variable, function, or macro), then `IIndex.findReferences()` to find all usages of the macro.

The return type of `findReferences()` is an array of `IIndexName`, which has methods to access the filename and line number of the usage.